# Caching large numbers of ActiveRecord objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, activerecord

There's an oft-called method in my Rails application that retrieves ~200 items from the database. Rather than do this again and again, I store the results using `Rails.cache.write`. However, when I retrieve the results using `Rails.cache.read`, it's still very slow: about 400ms. Is there any way to speed this up?

This is happening in a controller action, and I'd prefer users not have to wait so long to load the page.

Comment: Are these super-objects that hold lots and lots of data?  Reading 400 objects from the cache *should not* normally take that long.

Comment: No, they really aren't that big. That's why I'm so confused what's taking so long. I'll do a little more investigation.

Answer (score 0):

FYI regarding Rails caching, from the Rails Guides, "...It’s important to note that query caches are created at the start of an action and destroyed at the end of that action and thus persist only for the duration of the action."

If you can share the method, I may be able to help more quickly. Otherwise, a couple performance best practices:

- Use `.includes` to avoid N+1 queries. Define this in the model and
  call it in the controller.
- How are your indexes set-up (if any)?